# Send different and alternate Classes as parameters to create a specific List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, methods, parameters

I have code that is long and has similar methods.

Can I transform similar methods into a single method that will receive a Class when called up?

```
        public void GridViewCareer()
    {
        var lista = new List<Career>();
        lista = bll.SelectCareerBLL();
        gvCareer.DataSource = lista;
        gvCareer.DataBind();

    }
        public void GridViewBrand()
    {
        var lista = new List<Brand>();
        lista = bll.SelectCareerBLL();
        gvBrand.DataSource = lista;
        gvBrand.DataBind();

    }
```

I have 10 codes just like that, but with different Names And list types (career, brand, artist, clothing...)

I want a SINGLE method and the calls like

- GridViewSelect(Brand);
- GridViewSelect(Artist);
- GridViewSelect(Carrer);

I don't know 1-how to send a Class as parameter and 2-what type of Item I use in the List

I don't know if it is possible, so is there another way to transform 400 code lines into 20 code lines?

ps: I know how to pass the "instances" just like gvCareer and gvBrand

- Default layer

  ```
      public void GridViewCareer()
  {
      var lista = new List<Career>();
      lista = bll.SelectCareerBLL();
      gvCareer.DataSource = lista;
      gvCareer.DataBind();

  }
  ```
- Business Logic Layer

  ```
      public List<Career> SelectCareerBLL()
  {
      var lista = new List<Career>();
      lista = dal.SelectCareer();
      return lista;
  }
  ```
- Data Access Layer

  ```
      public List<Career> SelectCareer()
  {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
      {

          var SQL = "select * from  Career";
          var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

          var lista = new List<Career>();
          con.Open();
          try
          {
              var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              while (dr.Read())
              {
                  var obj = new Career();
                  obj.CareerId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                  obj.CareerName = (string)dr[1].ToString();
                  obj.CareerIsAct = (string)dr[2].ToString();
                  obj.CareerNote = (string)dr[3].ToString();
                  lista.Add(obj);
              }
              dr.Close();
          }
          finally
          {
              con.Close();
          }
          return lista;
      }
  }
  ```

  And I have 10 tables and I'm doing that for each of them.

Comment: why do you need the lista variable? how does bll.SelectCareerBLL() knows what to return?Why don't you use  var lista =List<DTO.Clothing>()?

Comment: I am sorry, I have 3 layers and I show you only one, Im editing so you can understand

Comment: In GridViewBrand,do you mean  lista = bll.SelectBRAND();?

Comment: Yes, maybe I copied the wrong code because I'm editing trying the new codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Default layer

  ```
  public void GridView(Gridview gv,object datasource)
  {
      gv.DataSource = datasource;
      gv.DataBind();
  }
  ```

  Use it

  ```
  GridView(gvCareer,bll.SelectCareerBLL());
  ```
- Business Layer

  ```
  public List<Career> SelectCareerBLL()
  {
      return dal.SelectCareer();
  }

  public List<Career> SelectBrandBLL()
  {
      return dal.SelectBrand();
  }
  ```
- Data Layer

  ```
      public List<Career> SelectCareer()
      {
          return To("connectionString", "sql for careers", ToCarrer);
      }
      public List<Brand> SelectBrand()
      {
          return To("connectionString", "sql for brands", ToBrand);
      }
      private static Brand ToBrand(SqlDataReader arg)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException("Similar to ToCarrer");
      }

      private static Career ToCarrer(SqlDataReader dr)
      {
          return new Career()
          {
              CareerId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
              CareerName = (string)dr[1].ToString(),
              CareerIsAct = (string)dr[2].ToString(),
              CareerNote = (string)dr[3].ToString(),
          };
      }

      private static List<T> To<T>(string connectionString, string sql, Func<SqlDataReader, T> funct)
      {
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
          {
              var SQL = sql;
              var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

              var lista = new List<T>();
              con.Open();
              try
              {
                  var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  while (dr.Read())
                  {
                      lista.Add(funct(dr));
                  }
                  dr.Close();
              }
              finally
              {
                  con.Close();
              }
              return lista;
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: The "problem" is I dont know I could do that haha Thank you! Ok, it solves "half of the problem", because it solves my first layer, but in the 2 next I still have a lot of Similar Methods that coulb be just one if I know how to pass the Class

Comment: Ok, help me please, the Main Method is in the first layer just like instances/variables, and are they calling for the last layer Method? I dont understand what should I do with the brand ToBrand(), should I do exactly like you or exactly like the Career To Career? Ps: as I said above, Im still a begginer and I dont speak english so please dont be mad with me

Comment: @JeúCasulo Updated my answer

Comment: Dude! It really worked! hahaha I was "translating" the code thats why I take too long to answer, but its 100%, and I learned a lot with this code! So really thank you man! And sorry for all the "mess" I did! Now I am trying to use this "logic" to do something similar with the insert, delete and update, so my code well became clean and shorter! Thank you again man!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Below you find a simple console application that does what you want

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var l = GetList<Career>();
        }

        public static List<T> GetList<T>() where T : BaseClass
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }

        public static List<T> SelectCareer<T>(string cs, string query) where T : BaseClass, new()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {

                var SQL = query;
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

                var lista = new List<Career>();
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var obj = new T();
                        obj.Load(dr);
                        lista.Add(obj);
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                return lista;
            }
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual void Load(IDataReader dr)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Career : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Load(IDataReader dr)
        {
            CareerId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            CareerName = (string)dr[1].ToString();
            CareerIsAct = (string)dr[2].ToString();
            CareerNote = (string)dr[3].ToString();
        }

        public string CareerNote { get; set; }

        public string CareerIsAct { get; set; }

        public string CareerName { get; set; }

        public int CareerId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artist : BaseClass {}
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have 3 layers and I show you only one, Im editing so you can understand

Comment: Ok, let me see if I got that

1-the "GetList<Career>();" is in the first layer and calling for the second? 

2-the "return new List<t>();" is in the second layer and calling for the third and 

3 - finally the "public static List<T> SelecCarrer<T>..." is in the third?

4 - while the BaseClass and Carrer : BaseClass are the DataTransferObject
? Do not be mad at me Im still a begginer and I dont speak english so I dont understand everything so fast as I should